# Origen de la expresión "remanguillé" / "a la remanguillé"

Tags: etimología, modismos, historia, palabras-raras

[**Remanguillé**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Vs34hwz) y [**a la remanguillé**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Vs34hwz) aparecen en la edición actual del DLE como:

> **Remanguillé**
>   [sin definición]
>
> **a la remanguillé**
>   1. loc. adv. coloq. De forma desordenada. *Colocaron los muebles a la remanguillé.* U. t. c. loc. adj. *Una habitación a la remanguillé.*
>   2. loc. adv. De manera descuidada o imprecisa. *Hizo el presupuesto a la remanguillé.* U. t. c. loc. adj. *Un presupuesto a la remanguillé.*
>   3. loc. adv. De forma inadecuada. *Se fueron a la remanguillé.* U. t. c. loc. adj. *Una despedida a la remanguillé.*

Consultando el [**NTLLE**](http://ntlle.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUIMenuNtlle?cmd=Lema&sec=1.0.0.0.0.), parece que no fue incluida en el DLE hasta 1985 y con unas acepciones ligeramente diferentes:

> **remanguillé (a la).** loc. adv. fam: Estropeado, en mal estado.  En completo desorden, patas arriba.

Sin embargo, aparece ya en **1919** en [*Los hijos de nadie*](https://books.google.es/books?id=1uYAAAAAMAAJ&q=remanguill%C3%A9&dq=remanguill%C3%A9&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFhNn-1YLjAhUSlhQKHYTYBAkQ6AEINDAC) de Fernado Mora:

> ... crees que pué ascender a fenómeno quien dió aquel **remanguillé** y aquel otro de tirón?

Y una búsqueda en la [**Hemeroteca Digital**](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/index.vm) arroja casos de uso desde **1913** en adelante.
Por ejemplo, en *El Imparcial* (24/03/1913), describiendo una corrida de toros:

> Gallito comienza con un buen cambio: sigue toreando por naturales, preparados, de molinete, hasta de **«remanguillé»** ...

No he encontrado nada sobre su origen.
Tampoco aparece en el [**Diccionario de americanismos**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=remanguill%C3%A9) ni en el [**Fichero General de la RAE**](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html), por lo que me pregunto por el origen y evolución del significado de la palabra y de la locución.
Todos los ejemplos de uso que he encontrado parecen proceder de España, por lo que surge una cuestión adicional: ¿se utilizan / entienden fuera de España?

Comment: Estupendamente formulada la pregunta, consultando toda la documentación y las fuentes disponibles hasta agotar recursos. Mis dieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A finales del siglo XIX y principios del XX el idioma francés ejercía mucha influencia en el español. La terminación en *é* no es más, en el caso de *remanguillé*, que una chufla de dicho idioma, un modo de hacer festiva una palabra asemejándola a otro lenguaje, muy al estilo de lo que se hacía no hace mucho con palabras acabadas en *-eitor* para asemejarlas al *-ator* inglés, como en *Terminator*.

La influencia del francés se puede comprobar buscando en el CORDE. Así, vemos que se decía *la [matiné](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Oc1LY2S)* en vez de *la matinal*, *sopa de [puré](https://dle.rae.es/?id=UiDGgeX) a la Condé*, *bucles atusados a la Seviñé*, *críticos a la [cabriolé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6Sx6iX9)*, *ojo a la [virulé](https://dle.rae.es/?id=buPgz6o)*, etc. Es decir, el español medio estaba acostumbrado a ese sonido *-é* final como originario del país vecino.

Ahora bien, la cuestión es ¿qué palabra se afrancesó para formar este vocablo que ha conseguido perdurar en el tiempo? Eso lo ignoro, pero podemos establecer algunas teorías:

- [*Remangar*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Vs0YRuj). Levantar, recoger hacia arriba las mangas o la ropa. Si vas con las mangas o la falda remangada es que estás haciendo algo peliagudo y no quieres que se te ensucie la ropa. Ir remangado implicaría no ir correctamente vestido, por lo que la palabra da la imagen de descuido que dan también frases como "llevar el pelo a la remanguillé", e incluso la imagen de esfuerzo de "soy capaz de sacudir a la remanguillé" (ejemplo del CORDE de 1932).
- *Remangué*. Variante de la anterior, se usaba según el fichero general para definir "el pelo remangado sobre la frente". No encuentro casos de esta voz en el CORDE o la hemeroteca, pero bien podría haber generado *remanguillé* como versión jocosa.
- *Remaguear*. Tampoco la busquéis en el DLE. El fichero general la define como "ser flojo, mostrarse reacio", y *remaguero* como "flojo, poco activo". Esta palabra también daría la imagen de descuido, por lo que habría podido generar la voz *remanguillé* con influjo de *remangar*.

Comment: Merece la pena leer la [_emitología_ propuesta](https://emitologias.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/a-la-remanguille-origen/) para _remanguillé_.

Comment: @Charlie, esa web no era de broma?

Comment: @blonfu por supuesto, por eso he puesto "emitología" (de "mito") en cursiva, pero no por ello deja de merecer la pena leer la historia que se han inventado, sorprende la imaginación que tienen. Si hubiera sido una referencia a una web seria habría añadido su contenido a la respuesta, más que indicarlo como un simple comentario. :-)

Comment: @Charlie esa página de broma y su maleducado autor se pueden ir a ..